# Android Studio (Kotlin) - What method is to call when opening the taskbar of the phone?

Tags: java, xml, android-studio, kotlin, overriding

I have a little problem. I have a Bluetooht activity which contains two fragment. The goal of the first fragments is to know if the bluetooht is activated on the phone (Nothing complicated).
To do something clean I would like to update my fragment when the user opens the phone taskbar since he can activate bluetooht.

The problem is, I can't find the methods to call when opening or closing the taskbar.
I have already tried onResume but obviously it is not calling.

Does anyone have an idea?

thank you in advance